# displaying bars next to each other in jquery flot

Tags: jquery, flot

I am working on a flot graph where i have a few data points i want to display next to each other as bars per x axis, by default the bars overlap and i cant seem to find out where to do this.

I found a basic example of what im trying to do here:

[image: jquery chart]

Comment: I've never had mine overlap; can you post an example of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a plugin that gives more support for that type of graph: http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=159